# Matplotlib, how to put space in between bars?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a huge horizontal bar graph with 100 lines! So we dont see much at all. As shown in picture.
Is it possible to add space in between the bars, even if it means scrolling up and down it is no problem but at least see something right!
Thank all!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRoZZ.jpg

--------------code-------------------

```
df.plot(kind='barh',y='IP Equity',x='Flop',align='center', width=0.7)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))` and `df.plot(...., ax=ax)`

Comment: thx! it gets a bit better now, but still no space between the bars. Any way to add some space to make it look nicer?

Comment: You could make the fontsize smaller. `plt.yticks(fontsize=...)`